# USB-C superspeed Signal pass through connection issue

Tags: usb-c

The idea was to make a pass through super-speed signal connection (like a cable)between USB-C horizontal connector and USB-C vertical connector on a custom made PCB. where the device connects to the USB-C horizontal connector and host connects to the USB-C vertical connector. Below are the wiring connection and board layout. It is a four layer stack-up board and 90um thickness on both top and bottom layer.

[image]  [image]

Basically, I just wanted to create a right-angle setup due to space and design requirement. It is just a signal pass-through connection between host and device. I've followed 100R impedance followed with 0.15mm width. I heard 100R impedance wouldn't make much difference. Also, I came to know that I need to short D1_P to D2_P, and D1_N to D2_N for reversibility. It is working fine now.

But the problem I am facing now is

It detects only the high speed which is 480 Mbps not the super speed and Did I do any mistake on the wiring?

Your suggestions or guide would be much appreciated and helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I find it unlikely that for the whole path the impedances all match up.

Comment: again I've looked into differential pairs they are 100% matched with each other except two of the pairs got 99.9%. is that going to be the issue?

Comment: You need a simulation. People doo crazy stuff for your requirements, like backdrilling, etc. Anyway without a simulation you can't know what's the problem.

Comment: Can you share your layer stack up? Material specs and thicknesses. If it's 4 layers, are both inner layers unbroken ground planes?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, backdrilling doesn't make any sense for top to bottom transitions.

Comment: Yes, but simulation does. Backdrilling is just an example of crazy stuff that may come out of simulation.

Comment: @ThePhoton, it is a 4 layer PCB. thickness is 1.6mm. I have made a separate cut-out ground ratsnet only around the highspeed area where these 2 connectors are placed on layer2 and layer 3.

Comment: We need to see the inner layers. You're running high speed data pairs over top and bottom, so you will need reference planes on both inner layers. If you are referencing between power and ground, you will need decouple caps at the transitions. If its ground on both inners, you will need stitching vias at the transitions. The old 'USB will run over damp string" doesn't work anymore when you are throwing 5-10Gbit/s signals.

Answer (score 2):

5 Gbps (or 10?) is no joke. Very small impedance discontinuities can badly impact the signal integrity.

The biggest problem I see here is lack of return path vias where signals transition between top and bottom layers.

Whenever the signal transitions from layer 1 to layer 4, the return currents beneath the microstrips need to transition from layer 2 to layer 3. This means one or more ground vias are needed near every signal via. A transition without these vias will present an inductive discontinuity, and also likely cause radiation as return currents find a path between the ground planes.

In addition,

- USB high speed and superspeed are specified with 90-ohm characteristic impedance, not 100 ohms. In the last few millimeters before a termination, a 11% error in Z0 might not be a big issue, but for a board placed in the middle of the overall signal path it could be a real problem. You should design the trace geometry to target 90 ohms.
- You haven't told us whether you specified the board fab should be responsible for controlled impedance or if you just specified the geometry and stack-up. If you haven't given the fab responsibility for impedance, then variations in copper plating thickness, prepreg thickness, etc., could be causing variations in Z0 that are out of your control at layout time.
- You haven't told us your material spec. Just asking for "FR-4" could result in substantial variation in dielectric constant, invalidating your calculated characteristic impedance. You should use a material with a well-defined Dk, and specify it by the laminate vendor's product designation (for example, "Isola FR408 HR"). If you're specifying geometry rather than Z0, you should specify the material glass weave and resin content (after making sure your desired material is available to your fab shop).
- Your traces are close enough together that there could be cross-talk between them (this also depends on the dielectric thicknesses that you haven't shared). Return currents sharing transition vias could also contribute to cross-talk.

Comment: ~90um thickness has been used on both top and both. I've informed the Fab regarding the 100R impedance controlled tracks.

Comment: @Dhinesh, Please edit your question to include the information needed to give you a good answer.

Comment: Hi, I have started to layout a 90R impedance controlled tracks. I have some questions.Sorry, Do I need to ask you further here in comments or do I need to edit the question? please direct me

Comment: @Dhinesh, if they're new questions, you should post them as new questions. When you post a question, you should include all the information needed to answer it.

Comment: Thanks Photon. I will try to include all information I know.

Comment: Hi Photon, I have posted a new question. Below is the link. I believe that I have provided all the information you needed. If not please let me know thanks. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389795/achieving-90r-impedance-for-usb-type-c-on-a-four-layer-board

Comment: Hi photon did you manage to look into the post? Is that sounds correct? Your guide would be helpful.