# Achieving 90R impedance for USB Type C on a four layer board

Tags: usb-c

I have started routing the 90R controlled impedance tracks for the USB. I've got the information from the manufacturer to use a trace width of 0.22mm and trace spacing of 0.125mm to achieve 90R impedance. Could anyone help me with my doubts?

These are the images of PCB layer stack-up followed from ZOT
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

See the above-attached PCB layout image,

1. Are all the yellow circled ground vias sufficient for the return current?
2. Are the tracks far enough to avoid the crosstalk? As I have set the track spacing to 0.125mm as per the manufacturer instructions.

Please let me know if it is good to go. Thanks

Comment: .07 or .075 mm dielectric is available, but is thinner than you 'd usually use if not doing very high layer counts. Consider going to .1 or .127 mm dielectric. You'll end up with wider traces, but that will mean lower loss and less likely to mess up the Z0 due to under/over-etching.

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks. are you talking about substrate dielectric? I heard normally the FR4 dielectric comes around 4? I am not sure the fab guys can do .1 or .127mm?

Comment: I'm talking about the thickness of the dielectric. The number you have as 0.07. You are correct, for FR-4 the dielectric constant will be around 4.5-4.7. But you can buy it in different sheet thicknesses.

Comment: @ThePhoton Hi Photon, I've edited my question now. Could you please clarify the two doubts I've asked. Thanks

Comment: If you really need to know, the best way to find out is with an EM simulation. Working at 5-10 Gbps it's not really safe to just work from rules of thumb and best practices. (First issue I see is there is one set of vias in RX1_P/N that doesn't have ground return vias around it)

Comment: @Thephoton, my bad I forgot to put. So are you happy with the via’s placed? Make sense to me. I will need to check if there is any free EM simulation tool available.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you it doesn't matter if I'm happy with the design or not. It matters whether the design produces excess reflections, which nobody can tell you just by looking at a screenshot from Eagle. Above 1 or 2 Gbps, everything gets very fussy and you can't just design things by eyeballing them, if you want to be confident they'll work.

Comment: Changing routing layers across 1.54 mm PCB is always a bad idea.

Comment: @AliChen Thanks. What would you recommend then? could you please explain?